# Get Year from String (e.g. Rogue Assassin 2007)

Tags: .net, regex, vb.net, string

I can't seem to figure out how to take the year from say `Rogue Assassin 2007` and return:

```
moviename = "Rogue Assassin" 'Whitespace doesn't matter
movieyear = "2007" 'Whitespace doesn't matter
```

However, I can't get it to work. I have been trying the following:

```
    If System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.IsMatch(fn, "[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]") Then 'Is this right?
        Dim mtemp As String() = fn.Split(" ") 'Movie temp array
        myear(0) = mtemp.Last 'Attempting to set year to the last split
        For Each z As String In mtemp 'Adding the other elements in mtemp together to remake the title
            If z IsNot mtemp.Last Then
                mtitle(0) = z & " " 'Movie title
            Else
                Exit For
            End If
        Next
        ...
    Else
        ...
    End If
```

Any help greatly appreciated!

Comment: Are you always guaranteed to have a year in the name?  Will the year always be four characters or could it be two?  Are you able to pre-format the year value to make it easier to recognize?

Comment: This is just one part of about 5 if statements...First 2 are year in curly brackets, year in square brackets, then this, then if year is in directory name then lastly, search just by title.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
1) Regular expression for matching year strings containing year 1800 to 2013 (ideal regex for obtaining movie year from the title)

1[89][0-9]{2}|200[0-9]|201[0-3]

2) Regular expression for matching year strings containing year from 1800 onwards.

1[89][0-9]{2}|20[0-9]{2}

Have tested the pattern (1) for the below movie titles:

Die Hard 2 1990 -> 1990
Django Unchained (2012) -> 2012
This Is 40 (2012) -> 2012
The Twilight Saga: Breaking Dawn - Part 2 - 2012 -> 2012
Die Hard 4.0 2007 -> 2007
```

Assumptions:

Since the year format is not specified in your question, and it is assumed that year will always be a 4 digit.

Movie titles can contain other 4 digits as well, and hence the year is particularly matched from 1800 to 2013 [which can get year values from most of the movie titles, and this reduces junk data being matched. consider this is to serve your needs for now :) ].

Answer (score 2):

You can try

```
Dim r As Regex = new Regex("(.*)\s+([0-9]+)$");
Dim match As Match = System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Match("Rogue Assassin 2007")
```

Above code will capture the match into 2 groups, and then you can retrieved the captured with match.Groups(1).Captures(0).Value and match.Groups(1).Captures(1).Value

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/twcw2f1c.aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=vb#code-snippet-2

Comment: There is a slight problem with this, in that it could match number tokens that are potentially not dates,for example, 90215 of the title "Beverly Hills 90215."

Comment: I am no Regexer ... will your Regex work for "Die Hard 2 1990"?

Comment: it won't work for  "Die Hard 2 1990", but it would work with "(.*)\s+([0-9]+)$"

Comment: So...Which expression are people recommending? `".*\s+([0-9]+)$"` or `"(\w+)\s+([0-9]+)"`

Comment: \w has some other problem. It doesn't include space, so you would returns "Assassin" as the first capture group

Comment: to handle "Beverly Hills 90215", you could use {4}, i.e., "(.*)\s+([0-9]{4})"

Comment: I put `()` around my original code, and now it works fine. I'll be back later if something starts playing up :D

Comment: If you would validate the year between 1900 and 2099, you could use (.*)\s+((19|20)[0-9]{2}). Anyway, playing with regular expression is fun.